# How to put a structure of Fréchet space on $\Gamma(E)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, differential-topology, vector-bundles

Let $\pi: E \to M$ a smooth vector bundle over M. If $(M,g^{M})$ and $(E,g^{E})$ are complete manifolds. Consider $\nabla$ a conection on $E$. We can define these semi-norms

$\displaystyle{\left\|\sigma\right\|_{n}=\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sup_{x\in M}\max_{\{g^{E}_x(v_x^i,v_x^i)=1\}}|\nabla_{v_{x}^{j}}\ldots\nabla_{v_{x}^{1}}\sigma(x)|}$.

How to prove $\displaystyle{d(\sigma,\eta)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}\frac{\left\| \sigma-\eta \right\|_{n}}{\left\|\sigma-\eta \right\|_{n}+1}}$ is a complete metric in $\Gamma(E)$?

Comment: I tried show on coordinates chart...

Comment: I tried show on coordinates chart...
I tried show thar $\left \cdot\right|_{1}$ was complete.
Let $(U,\phi)$ a chart of M, ${e_{k)}$ ortonormal local frame of $E$ in $\pi^{-1}(U)$ and $X=\sum x_j\partial_j$ a vector field.

Let $\sigma_n=\sum b_n^{k}e_k$ Cauchy sequence in $\Gamma^1(E)$, i tried prove the convergence looked 
$$\nabla_{X}\sigma_n=\sum_{k}(\sum_{i,j}x_i b^{j}_{n}\Gamma^{k}_{ij}+\sum_{i}x_i\frac{\partial b^{k}_{n}}{\partial x_i})E_{k}$$